# Front-end JavaScript pattern to ignore previous request responses

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not much of a front-end dev - a user might click a submit button to submit an AJAX request (this is a SPA), and the user might click the button again a few seconds later if they want to try a different setting. I could add an overlay and prevent them from submitting until the response comes back. But let's say I don't want to use the overlay method - is there some programming pattern I can use (closures maybe?) to ignore all the responses except the response for the most recent request?

Here is some code as an example:

```
define([

        '+appState',
        '#allModels',
        '#allCollections',
        'form2js',
        'ejs',
        'underscore',
        'react',
        '#allFluxActions'
    ],

    function (appState, models, collections, form2js, EJS, _, React, allFluxActions) {

        var actions = allFluxActions['FileAction'];

        var UploadFileView = React.createClass({


            handleSubmit: function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                this.props.clearUploadResult();

                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('file-0', this.state.file);


                if (!this.props.mappingType) {
                    alert('undefined mapping type.');
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('mapping type selected:', this.props.mappingType);
                }

                this.props.setStatus('PENDING');

                const self = this;

                return $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://172.x0.x.x1:4000/upload',
                    data: data,
                    headers: {
                        'x-baymax-mapping-type': this.props.mappingType
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false

                }).done(function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    if (resp && resp.responseJSON && resp.responseJSON.success) {
                        self.props.setUploadResult('No upload errors, all clear.');
                    }
                    else if (resp && resp.responseJSON && resp.responseJSON.error) {
                        self.props.setUploadResult(resp.responseJSON.error);
                    }
                    else {
                        self.props.setUploadResult(resp);
                    }

                }).fail(function (resp) {
                    if (resp && resp.responseJSON && resp.responseJSON.error) {
                        self.props.setUploadResult(resp.responseJSON.error);
                    }
                    else {
                        self.props.setUploadResult('Fail - unexpected server error.');
                    }
                });

            },

            handleImageChange: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                this.props.clearUploadResult();

                var reader = new FileReader();
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                var fileName = document.getElementById('fileName');
                fileName.innerHTML = file.name;
                console.log('File Data:', file);

                reader.onloadend = () => {
                    this.setState({
                        file: file
                    });
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            },

            render: function () {

                return (
                    <div className='row fileUploadForm'>
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <div className='nine columns'>
                                <label className='fileUpload'>File Upload
                                    <input type='file' name='file' id='fileUpload' onChange={this.handleImageChange}/>
                                </label>
                                <span id='fileName'></span>
                                <div id="upload-submit-button-div" className="upload-submit-button-div">
                                    <button className='button-primary fileFormSubmit' type='submit'
                                            onClick={this.handleSubmit} value='Submit'>Submit
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                )
            }

        });


        return UploadFileView;

    });
```

When the user clicks submit (after choosing a file) the response might take 5-10 seconds. Our test engineer will get impatient and try some other files before the last response comes back. Upon a submit button click how can ignore previous responses? I was thinking of some sort of timestamp trick using closures but I am not sure. Kinda stumped.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the $.ajax request and then abort() it before sending the next one.

```
...
let lastAjax = null;
...
var UploadFileView = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function (e) {
    ...  
    if (!!lastAjax) {
      lastAjax.abort();
    }

    lastAjax = $.ajax({
      ...
    });

    return lastAjax;
  },
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do 4 things:

- when a file is selected, which will trigger the change event of the file input, [abort](http://help.dottoro.com/ljomfaxv.php) all pending requests
- on submit, add the [boolean attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#boolean-attributes) disabled to the button (and remove it later on if necessary) so that you won't have duplicate requests
- once the file has been selected, (re-)attach the event handler—that is only executed [once](http://api.jquery.com/one/)—to the submit button and remove its disabled attribute
- for the UX, add a spinner/loader

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old, but it showed up when I was searching for this technique.

I believe you can compare a global variable with a local copy to see if the response is "stale" and ignore it when it is:

```
let counter = 0;

handleSubmit: function (e) {
        // ... your stuff ...
        let self = this;
        ++this.counter;
        let localcounter = counter;
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            //... etc ...
        }).done(function (resp) {
            if (localcounter != self.counter) {
               // ignore stale response!
            } else {
               // process result
            }
        }).fail(function (resp) {
            if (localcounter != self.counter) {
               // ignore stale response!
            } else {
               // process failure
            }
        });
}
```